# Find the perfect value for K in K-Means Algorithm (Apache Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am working on a project that involved anomaly detection using the K-means model.

However, to get almost exact and precise results, I need to find the optimum value of K.

My algorithm relies on the idea that outliers in my model will generally be placed on a cluster by themselves. Usually "normal" data will be clustered together with other normal data, but anomalous data will make their own cluster, hence indicating an anomaly. However, I need to find the optimal value of K for my algorithm to work and see if it is good or not.

Any ideas on how to find a good K value?

This is a sample file with "normal" dummy data that I'll be using to train my model:

```
Name    Size    Records
File1   1013    105727
File2   990     104230
File3   1520    110542
File4   2198    115369
File5   2026    113430
File6   1844    112105
File7   1216    108159
File8   1520    110408
File9   1013    105359
File10  1317    108428
File11  1925    112553
File12  1449    109456
File13  1803    111436
File14  2036    115937
File15  2043    116383
```

Comment: Have you considered using another clustering method such as Hierarchical clustering? It can help you to choose K if you do not have a test set with a "true" clustering.

Comment: And how is that? I just went through Apache's Spark doc and they do have support for Hierarchical clustering (Bisecting k-means), but what is the difference and how can this help me find K and not the normal k-means?

Comment: there are implementations of dbscan for spark. This one seems to be very well suited for your task. If you want to find the optimal k you probably need to uses non-parametric bayesian approaches. E.g., a chinese restaurant process. Will be pain in the neck.

Comment: [Elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) is one of the popular method for finding optimal value of K, but I am not sure how to do it on spark (distributed environment)

Comment: K-means is really really bad at anomaly detection. I'd rather use a real outlier detection algorithm. Try ELKI which has several such algorithms and which is much faster than Spark.

Comment: Thank you! So far I have used the hierarchical version of KMeans (Bisecting KMeans) which is supposed to automatically find an optimal value of K for your records. I still have to try this with real data and see if it effectively works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hierarchical version of K-means. Apache Spark has the BisectingKMeans which works in that manner. It calculates a good value of K depending on the amount of records that you have. That way you don't have to define K (cluster) when you create a model. You can still set a value of K if you're not comfortable with the one it assigned, but it usually works just fine.

Thanks to @Peheje for the tip.

Comment: Bisecting K-means won't give you optimal value of K. It defaults to 4.